# YouAtNotes HTML5 upload control - working with external db source

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, xpages

I've used the HTML5 upload control from http://julianbuss.net/xpages-html5-multifile-upload-with-drag-and-drop/ made by Jullian Buss.
I've made it more dynamic with more params. Redid it so you can upload your files in to different RichText on the same document. And Included the drag&drop functionality. It works perfectly. Except, when I put this control in my application, which uses data source from another database. Application is used only for design and log docs, but sources are all from different databases.

Eg.:

```js
<xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="docFORM"
    action="editDocument"
    documentId="#{javascript:return sessionScope.docId;}">
    <xp:this.databaseName>
      <![CDATA[#{javascript:return getDatabase("someDatabase"); }]]>
     </xp:this.databaseName>
   </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Does anyone have any idea, how I could post the uploaded files to other database and return response in filedownload table?

Comment: When you use a computed data source... your URL will look very different. The upload control might rely on such information. Check how it computes the destination

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for dominoDocument's databaseName is just database's path and name:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="document1"
        formName="docFORM"
        action="editDocument"
        documentId="#{sessionScope.docId}"
        databaseName="yourFolder/yourDatabase.nsf">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

You can calculate databaseName like

```
        databaseName="#{javascript:'yourFolder' + '/' + 'yourDatabase.nsf'}">
```

or

```
        databaseName="#{sessionScope.databaseName}">
```

too. I tested it and it all works well with YouAtNotes HTML5 upload control.

Comment: Yes.. Just figured it out. My problem was elsewhere. I lost two days... The problem was(bear in mind I still don't get why) I had it inside a xp:panel. Which had a render computation. When I removed that render computation it started to work. It was always rendered correctly. However somehow the response did not get to filedownload control. Somehow the render computation broke the partial refresh of filedownload table.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing code but sounds as if you ran into JSF lifecycle issues

Comment: Did anyone encounter a problem in IE 10. I get "Access denied" error, when selecting the files for upload.